# Remove black bar bottom of UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I remove the black bar at the bottom of the camera view and make the photo preview take up the entire screen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, in iOS7 image picker move to whole screen but prior to iOS7 you may not have full screen camera view so that you may need to apply transformation in your screen view

if your device is running iOS6 (4 inch):

```
CGAffineTransform cameraTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.930);
```

if your device is running iOS6 (3.5 inch):

```
CGAffineTransform cameraTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.260);
```

if your device is running on iOS7 (4 inch)

> ```
> CGAffineTransform cameraTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.670);
>                 self.picker.cameraViewTransform = cameraTransform;
> ```

Comment: This heavily distorts my picture, is there any way to stop the distortion?

Comment: Change the transform scale the above transformation scale is for 4inch devices that uses iOS prior to iOS7.

Comment: What scale would you recommend for 5/5S?

Comment: CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.670); for 5/5s. This will distorts the picture because the full screen size on 4inch devices are not the optimal aspect sizes for images. Otherwise you may need to use the default control for camera view.

Comment: @UsmanAwan I tried this but the image looks distorted or zoomed in. Is there a solution that would more generic and work for all screen sizes?